# Is it possible to use CGContextScaleCTM to create a retina image?

Tags: objective-c, macos, scaling, retina-display, cgcontext

So I'm creating a `CGContextRef` here:

```
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 0, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host);
```

I then draw a `CGLayer` on that `CGContextRef`:

```
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(bitmapContext, dest, cgLayer);
```

When I resize the context with `CGContextScaleCTM`:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapContext, 1/self.desiredScale, 1/self.desiredScale);
```

I end up with an image twice as small, but it also has half the DPI. I want to basically half the size of an image while doubling the DPI to turn it into a retina image.

I haven't been able to find any good leads, so any information would be great

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You want to create the context with the "true pixel" size (double usually, triple for iPhone 6+) and use the multiplier as the scale. Basically, the opposite of what you're doing.

So, to get a 200x200pt image at 2x:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 400, 400, ...)
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 2, 2)
```